# Calling result of a function call as a function in javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, anonymous-function

I recently came across some node.js code that has an anonymous function enclosed in parentheses immediately after a function call. Could somebody please explain to me what is going on with the syntax here?

```
var fs = require('./continuable-style-fs');

fs.readFile('mydata.txt')(function (text) {
  // Do something
  console.log(text);
}, function (error) {
  // Handle error
  throw error
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`continuable-style-fs` is returning versions of the built-in `fs` methods that return functions instead of accepting a callback as an argument.

With that in mind, the callback is being passed to the function returned by `fs.readFile()`. The callback is then called when the read is complete, just like the original `fs.readFile()` would.

When looking at [the code for continuable-style-fs](https://github.com/creationix/howtonode.org/blob/246cbb8e9d70f917de9667ec7e2ca61951a0ee44/articles/control-flow-part-ii/continuable-style-fs.js), the second function passed is the function that receives errors. This is more promise-like than the "error-first" callback approach of async node core methods.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is this, the following code:

```
fs.readFile('mydata.txt')(function (text) {
  // Do something
  console.log(text);
}, function (error) {
  // Handle error
  throw error
});
```

Can be translated to this:

```
var file_reader = fs.readFile('mydata.txt');
file_reader(function (text) {
  // Do something
  console.log(text);
}, function (error) {
  // Handle error
  throw error
});
```

Which can then be translated to this:

```
function read_file_handler (text) {
    // Do something
    console.log(text);
}

function file_error_handler (error) {
    // Handle error
    throw error
}

var file_reader = fs.readFile('mydata.txt');

file_reader(read_file_handler, file_error_handler);
```

Basically, javascript allows you to:

1. Treat functions as data
2. Immediately use the result of any expression or function call

Number 2 is interesting. Because it allows you to do things like this:

```
function foo () {
    return "a,b,c";
}
var abc_array = foo().split(',');
```

Note that in the example above `split` is a `String` method but we can call it immediately after `foo()` because it returns a string.

Similarly we can do this:

```
function foo () {
    return function () {console.log('hello')}
}
foo()();
```

Here calling `foo()` returns a function. We can assign it to a variable and call that but we can also call it immediately as we do above.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `fs.readFile('mydata.txt')` returns a function, which is immediately invoked.

It might make more sense to look at it like so...

```
var fs = require('./continuable-style-fs');

var fn = fs.readFile('mydata.txt');

fn(function (text) {
  // Do something
  console.log(text);
}, function (error) {
  // Handle error
  throw error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without you posting the function require() it's a little hard to tell since we don't know exactly what that returns. If you provide more info I'm sure I can figure it out, otherwise I'm slightly guessing at the answer right now. OK so here it goes:

in JavaScript you can have an anonymous function that takes a parameter. You would initiate that function as follows:

```
(function (variable){
 ...
 ...
})(myVariable);
```

So if required() returns an object, then fs.readFile () would be a method attached to that object (through prototyping). In this case it looks like it's a method that itself returns an anonymous function that will then receive either the variable from the `//Do something` section or it will receive the error/variable from the `//Handle error`

So in the end the you'll have

```
fs.readFile('mydata.txt')(someVariable);
```

Which if readFile does return an anonymous function then it will look like:

```
(function foo (variable){})(someVariable);
```

This as another answers mentions is simply a slightly different approach to using callbacks. I hope that helps, and is clear.

Comment: If my answer is not that clear, you should read mscdex's answer below as he's talking about the same thing and is more concise about it.

Comment: I got the code from [this](http://howtonode.org/control-flow-part-ii) blog entry. It is talking about nodes old promise based system. I follow what you are saying up to the point that the function gets evaluated into some variable. What I don't understand is where does that variable get used and under what name would it be stored? In the example above, would the return value of `fs.readFile('mydata.txt')` get passed in as an argument to the anonymous function?